# Find all shootable cells in grid game

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-engine

I am making simple grid like game ( grid is matrix 128x128) and matrix is filled with 0 and 1 ( 1 bullet can pass through, 0 bullet cannot pass through cannot continue to travel anymore, also I have bullet range 32 cells).
I am standing for example at position (32,89). Can anyone suggest me any efficient algorithm for calculating all shootable fields ? ( I know to calculate on simple way with simple checking every filed in range, but I wonder is there better idea)

Comment: Do bullets travel only in discrete directions? Can you shoot only in 90° (or 45°) angles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a more efficient algorithm. Eric Lippert has written an excellent series on shadow casting in grid games. If I understand correctly, this is exactly what you need.

- [Shadowcasting in C#, Part One](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/12/shadowcasting-in-c-part-one.aspx)
- [Shadowcasting in C#, Part Two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/15/shadowcasting-in-c-part-two.aspx)
- [Shadowcasting in C#, Part Three](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/19/shadowcasting-in-c-part-three.aspx)
- [Shadowcasting in C#, Part Four](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/22/shadowcasting-in-c-part-four.aspx)
- [Shadowcasting in C#, Part Five](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/27/shadowcasting-in-c-part-five.aspx)
- [Shadowcasting in C#, Part Six](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/12/29/shadowcasting-in-c-part-six.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are no much better way.

It would be possible if the points where you would shot where positions in a list. In this case you could eliminate some checks by removing other elements from the list.

If your grid doesn't change, you can evaluate it for every position an save for later use.
This would use 128*128*(2pi*range) memory which is about 4MB.
If that is the case you can save it for every possible angle, resulting in a max of 2pi*range=202 positions, then do 202 checks instead of 1024(32*32) needed before.